# External Js file not loading

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a reason this doesnt work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script 

     <script
      src="C:/Users/juniper/Documents/practiceCode/public/server/screen.js">
     </script>
     </head> 
    <body>
     <img src="blue.png" usemap="#map">
    <map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,400,160" onclick="hideScreen()">
   </map>
   <style>
    img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
     map {
   position: absolute;
   }
  </style>
```

This is the screen.js

```
  function hideScreen() {
    alert("hitBackButton");
  }
```

the point is it sends out an alert when I press that section of the hotmap, However I think it doesn't work because the screen.js file is used after this file. So it doesnt load in time. what could be the issue with the external js file?

Comment: `src` is an attribute of `script`: `<script src="...">`

Comment: What do you mean by `main.js`? Your code references `screen.js`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/public/server/screen.js">         </script>
        ^ not <src
```

update

if you're running a server you can use path

```
<script src="http://SERVER/public/server/screen.js"></script>
```

or if not then use a relative path from the folder the html file is running

```
<script src="/public/server/screen.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry i mistyped, it actually does look like that and it doesnt work

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplehttpserver

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 <script 
  <src="C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/public/server/screen.js">
 </script>
```

To:

```
 <script src="relativePathToFolder/screen.js"></script>
```

And, don't use absolute file system paths. Use a relative path.

Comment: sorry i mistyped, it actually does look like that and it doesnt work

Comment: @juniperWhite Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error in your developer's console?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your page is unaware of the c: drive location, if you want to provide a file for local use only the it's `file://c:/...` otherwise you have to put on a web server like apache, nginx, etc. If you want a simple web server you can start from the command line and point to a directory you can try [devd.io](https://github.com/cortesi/devd).